# Install VirtualBox guest additions - unable to fetch some archives

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am trying to install the VirtualBox guest additions in to my ubuntu vm using the following command `sudo apt-get install -y dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. I get the following error: [image: error]

I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, `udo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` and `sudo apt-get clean`

It seems a version 2.8.1 exists in the same folder.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

PS: I have close to 0 Linux knowledge, a gui approach would be preferred

Comment: Your output suggests that you are running Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan). That release of Ubuntu reached End Of Life in July 2020. It no longer receives security patches, and we no longer answer questions about it. You should migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *already stated, but pasted due to links*

Comment: If you don't want to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months (as required by 19.10 or a non-LTS release) you should stick to LTS or *long-term-support* releases.

Comment: Sadly I can not choose the ubuntu version, we are given a virtual machine file (.ova) and have to run some preinstalled software on it (starting the vm and running the software is not a problem). How can I update ubuntu? I did run sudo apt-get update already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: VBox Guest Additions hasn't used dkms for quite a while now, if you have any vaguesly recent VBox (6.1.x, 6.0.x) just go ahead and try to run the installer (I assume you're following out-of-date instructions, just like the out-of-date OS they gave you...)